# Ansible: get list of files printed using find module

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook as below and I am trying to find list filename to stdout with find module:

```
[root@server local]# cat permissions.yaml
---
- hosts: centos

  tasks:
    - name: Set permissions
      find:
        paths: "/home/portaladmin/cq/author/crx-quickstart/repository/workspaces/crx.default/"
        patterns: "*.tar"
        register: tar_files

    - debug: msg=tar_files
```

And when I have executed `ansible-playbook` command I am getting error as find module doesn't have register parameter.

```
[root@server local]#
    [root@server local]# ansible-playbook permissions.yaml
    Vault password:

    PLAY [centos] ******************************************************************

    TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
    ok: [local]

    TASK [Set permissions] *********************************************************
    fatal: [local]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "unsupported parameter for module: register"}
            to retry, use: --limit @/home/root/ansible/local/permissions.retry

    PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    local                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix indentation:

```
- name: Set permissions
  find:
    paths: "/home/portaladmin/cq/author/crx-quickstart/repository/workspaces/crx.default/"
    patterns: "*.tar"
  register: tar_files
```

`register` is a task parameter not an action (module) parameter.